# load UIViewController view over singleViewController style app

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have created a single view based application. I was wanting to overlay UIViewControllers as I needed them, for instance like a modal view thing where if some values are populated then load the next view until you do something there and you can come back.

This is the code I have

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSMutableDictionary *tempPrefs = [prefsController readPrefs];
    NSString *tempName = [tempPrefs objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *tempProduct = [tempPrefs objectForKey:@"Product"];


// usedbefore so skip first view (first view == login view
    if ((tempName.length != 0) && (tempProduct.length != 0)) {
        // you have values, enter new room without checking
        [self loadGetProListViewController];
    }
}

- (void) loadGetProListViewController {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    getProListViewController = [[GetProListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetProListViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:getProListViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

However once this method has been reached its executed but nothing is happening..

If anyone could tell me how to create modal viewControllers or some description that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried viewDidAppear enstead willAppear?

Comment: No, I have breakpointed it and viewwillappear is working.. I was wanting to perform this action before the view is loaded.. that way the user might never need to see the log in again when loading the application.

Comment: If the compiler is there it doesn't mean it will work

Comment: Have you got some warnings like: "viewController not in the window hirerarchy ..."? Have you printed out "getProListViewController" instance? to make sure it isn't null

Comment: OH, Jezz didnt even see it but yes I have a warning this is what it says "Warning: Attempt to present <GetProListViewController: 0x1fd6ee90> on <ViewController: 0x1fd6e9f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: you can't present different viewController from UIViewController which is't presented yet, so -viewWillAppear doesn't work for you

Comment: I have added the code from viewWillAppear to viewdidLoad but still no difference

Comment: no, try to put it in didAppear method

Comment: That worked.. bit of an unsavory loading.. but its okay :P

Answer (score 0):

First you should be aware of [UIViewController lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html) to have an idea where you are able to present different `UIViewController`

Also I guess you have a bit incorrect architecture (maybe I wrong).

Let's imagine you have firstViewController on which -viewDidAppear method you present `getProListViewController`

Don't you think that presenting intermediate `firstViewController` is odd?

I'd reather you would move your `if` clause to level up. F.e:

```
/ usedbefore so skip first view (first view == login view
if ((tempName.length != 0) && (tempProduct.length != 0)) {
   // present your getProListViewController
} else {
   // present your "FirstViewController" (login or whatever)
}
```

And you haven't faced with your issue at the beginning

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    [self presentModalViewController: getProListViewController animated:YES];
```

instead of your presentviewcontroller

```
    [self presentViewController:getProListViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Isn't it deprecated? I suggest to use UINavigationController

Comment: I dont want UInavigationController as all of the views are to be modal